# label not found handling

Tags: batch-file

how do you handle label not found errors?
Here is the code that I think will be relevant:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
title EPIC BATCH!!!
echo welcome to the epic batch file there are lots of things you can do like
echo create (create a text file)
echo exit (close this window)
echo shutdown (shutdown your computer)
echo photos (look at some pictures)
echo color (change the color of the text and the background)
echo command prompt (open command prompt)
echo anti shutdown
echo.                 
echo type back at any time to go back
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want do?
```

The whole code (free to use if you want it)

````````
@echo off
:start
cls
title EPIC BATCH!!!
echo welcome to the epic batch file there are lots of things you can do like
echo create (create a text file)
echo exit (close this window)
echo shutdown (shutdown your computer)
echo photos (look at some pictures)
echo color (change the color of the text and the background)
echo command prompt (open command prompt)
echo anti shutdown
echo.                 
echo type back at any time to go back
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want do?
cls

:anti shutdown
"anti shutdown"
goto start

:command prompt
title command prompt
cmd.exe
goto start

:color
echo    1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
echo    2 = Green       A = Light Green
echo    3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
echo    4 = Red         C = Light Red
echo    5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
echo    6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
echo    7 = White       F = Bright White
echo the first number or letter you type will be the background the second will be the text
set /p COLOR= color? 
color %COLOR%
cls
goto start

:CREATE
set /p NAME=Name?
cls
set /p DOCUMENT= content?
echo %DOCUMENT% > %NAME%.txt
cls
goto start

:shutdown
shutdown -s -t 30 -c "quickly open antishutdown"
goto start

:photos
echo what photo do you want to look at?
set /p PHOTO= choices are dragon or flower 
goto %PHOTO%

:dragon
cls
echo                                 `-     .                                                           
echo                              +  //   :: `/`                                                        
echo                          `-::.`/+:://. .+-.-.`                       --.                           
echo                          :`.:::/+-.  o/:/:`  `::---.               -+-:.            `..            
echo                         -+/.`.:/./`::-:o-. `+/`                    +/o:          `+yhssoyh++       
echo                       `o:-`+y:hyyyhyhyhhhyoyyo+-                 :+/-/+--:   `/syddyyyys+:.        
echo                      `:s:hyyhhyssyyssoos+hhhhyyss/-            --++-. `..   -yd/.`-yyhhy+/         
echo                     `yyohhhhsyhyyhsssyyyyyshyyyhyys+.        -/+osyoys:::.  .md.    ....           
echo                   ``ohdyyyyhsyoyhyoossss+osoosyyyyy/.    ` :syhhhhhhhhoyyyso`-dd+-                 
echo                `-oys+shyhysos+hs+sosshs/oyyyys/shyhyo. `oyshsysyyy+++osyysohh+.:yhy+.              
echo                hyos/+//++sy+ooy+o/+oohhhhsoyyys/ysyy+ :shsyossyyyyy++os+sss+shy- .sdh+-            
echo              `/hdyo:+///oy++ooyyshoso+yshyy/hyy/hysh+.hsssosyyysyohos+s+y+ysomh/   .hhy/`          
echo          `-://///+++/////oshss-.  `:soooyhooyy/yyyhs:dssyoyyysosyssyyoyy+hsyyyy:    +dyh+          
echo        /yyysssso:--:+oo+//oo:      /syshssyys/syhhy-yys+ssyy+ohyssy::ysoy+shh+-   .+hmhdh          
echo        `+soss/.      /+s+/ss    .+sssyysyyssoyyhys.yhsyyoyy/+ysh+.`:yyoyyohy/ ``.syhddyho          
echo          `-/--/oo+++oosooy/+ `-/syyosyyysysyyhos -ohyossoh//sss/ -ysoyoossdyyyhhhydhhho+`          
echo              :yo///ooo+so:  .+syyosyysosshysyo  :hhyossoys/syhs  ohyhysssyyhhhhhhhydo/.            
echo                .+os+/::/-` osyhysyyyosyyhy/- `-yyhy+ssoyy/osdo. .+oho//++ohhyyhhso:`               
echo                 :o+.-     .oshhsyyysoysyyhos/hhsy+yossyyoooho.  +/d+///osyoo:-`                    
echo                   .  -+sossydmoyyyyssooosyyhyss+yossyyyossys    .+os+///////:-.-::-`               
echo                      +o++/syhy/so++/yysoy+ysysss++ooyyshsy:`     `-::+//+..:o++/..+/               
echo                     `o+//+/yyyoo++o+yysyoyos+yyo++sosyss+.             `  ./o-s   .                
echo                ://o++//`   .yyyssssssosoososoo+ss+/ss//                    /+/``                   
echo               /-.o:.`.+o     .+y+yoso+++sy+oossos/o:-                        ``                    
echo                 `:    .         o+s/++///+s+os++/-`                                                
echo                                 /++o++o//o`                                                        
echo                                   ./:o+//.                                                         
echo                                     `.:o/::-.                                                      
echo                                   .//o+:.``-o-                                                     
echo                                   //`o-    ``                                                      
echo                                    ` .                                                                                                                                                                
pause
cls
goto start

:flower 
cls
echo                      `/osyhhhhhhyyyyysso:`                                                          
echo                    :yhys+//::::::::::///oyso-                      `:+ssyyyysso+/.                  
echo                  .yhsss+:::::::::::::::::::/sy/`                 /shysssssssssssyyhs/`              
echo                 `dyssss/::::::::::::::::::::::oh-              +hyssssssssssssssssssyhs:            
echo                 syssssso:::::::::::::::::::::::/h/           :hyssssssssssssssssso++//+sh.          
echo                -dsssssss+:::::::::::::::::::::::/d:        `shssssssssssssssso+/::::::::od`         
echo                hyssssssss+:::::::::::::::::::::::+d`      `hysssssssssssssso/:::::::::::/ho         
echo                msssssssssso/::::::::::::::::::::::yo     `hyssssssssssssss/::::::::::::::+m         
echo               `mssssssssssss+/::::::::::::::::::::+d     ohssssssssssssso/:::::::::::::::/m`        
echo                msssssssssssssso/::::::::::::::::::/d-   -dssssssssssssss/:::::::::::::::::m.        
echo                yyssssssssssssssso+/::::::::::::::::yo  `dysssssssssssss/:::::::::::::::::/m.        
echo                -dssssssssssssssssssso+//:::::::::::od  yyssssssssssssso::::::::::::::::::+d         
echo                 yysssssssssssssssssssssssoo+++++++osm`+hssssssssssssss/::::::::::::::::::h/         
echo                 `hysssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdodsssssssssssssss::::::::::::::::::sy          
echo                  .hyssssssssssssssssssssssssyyhyyyyyhdyyhyssssssssssss::::::::::::::::/yy`          
echo                   `shssssssssssssssssssssyhyo/::-------:/+syhyssssssss:::::::::::::::+ho`           
echo                     -shyssssssssssssssyhy+:-...............-:shyssssss:::::::::::::+yy:             
echo                       .+yyysssssssssshy/-.....................-ohyssss/:::::::::/+yy/`              
echo                   ``...-:+oyhhhyyssydo-.........................:yhsss+:::::::/sys:`                
echo          .-:/+ossssssssooooosyhhdddm/............................-shsso::://sys+.                   
echo      ./ossooo+////::::::::::::::/sd+..............................-hyss+osso:.                      
echo    -oso//::::::::::::::::::::::::sd-.............................../mdmhysoooosssssssoo/-`          
echo  -ss/::::::::::::::::::::::::::::ys.................................myso++////::::::://+os+.        
echo -do:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::+ho.................................ms::::::::::::::::::::+s+`      
echo ys::::::::::::::::::::::::::::/osyy................................-ms/:::::::::::::::::::::oy:     
echo m+:::::::::::::::::::::////+oossssm:...............................odss+//:::::::::::::::::::/y+    
echo m+:::::::////++++oooooosssssssssssyh-............................./dssssssoo+///:::::::::::::::so`  
echo do:://+oosssssssssssssssssssssssssshy-.........................../dyssssssssssssoo+//:::::::::::ss  
echo yy/+ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssyh/-.......................-ohyssssssssssssssssssoo+/::::::::so 
echo /dossssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshh+-...................:ohysssssssssssssssssssssssso+/::::::h:
echo `msssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssydNhys/:-...........-:oyhysssssssssssssssssssssssssssss+/::::+d
echo  hysssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssyyysdyssyyyyso++//++osyyyNdyssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss+:::/m
echo  .yyssssssssssssssssssssssssssssyyo:+hssssssssssyyyyyso++//hohysssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssso::+d
echo    /hysssssssssssssssssssssssyyy/.`shssssssssssssso+/::::::os`shsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssso/yo
echo     .+yyssssssssssssssssssyyy+-  `yysssssssssssso/:::::::::/m  /hyssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssd`
echo       `:syyysssssssssssyyyo:`   .hyssssssssssss+::::::::::::d-  .shysssssssssssssssssssssssssssssd/ 
echo          `:oyyyyyyyyyso/-`     .hyssssssssssss/:::::::::::::so    -syysssssssssssssssssssssssssshs  
echo              ```````          .hyssssssssssss/::::::::::::::+d      -oyyysssssssssssssssssssssyho   
echo                              `hyssssssssssss+:::::::::::::::/m.       `:+syyyyysssssssssssyyyyo-    
echo                              yysssssssssssso:::::::::::::::::d:           `-:/+oossssyysso+:.       
echo                             :dsssssssssssss/:::::::::::::::::h/                                     
echo                             ohsssssssssssss::::::::::::::::::h/                                     
echo                             :dsssssssssssso::::::::::::::::::h:                                     
echo                              dssssssssssss+::::::::::::::::::h:                                     
echo                              /dsssssssssss/::::::::::::::::::d`                                     
echo                               shssssssssss/:::::::::::::::::+h                                      
echo                                +dyssssssss/::::::::::::::::+d.                                      
echo                                 .yhyssssss+::::::::::::/+sho.                                       
echo                                   ./syhyss+:::::://++syyo:`                                         
echo                                       `-/+oosyyhhyso+:`                                             
pause
cls
goto start

:back
cls
goto start

:EXIT
````````

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on providing code in the post. In this particular case there is absolutely no code that uses user input - how do you expect people to help you find issues in the code that is not shown?

Comment: fixed if you wish to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"label not found"` errors are caused by `goto` or `call` commands, but your "relevant code" have not anyone of them! I *assume* that a `goto %PROGRAM%` line is missing below the `cls`...

You should know that:

- Labels are formed by a *single word*, the label ends at first space.
- There is no way to handle a `goto notExist` error if the label not exists. However:
- It is possible to handle a `call :notExist` error. In this case the `errorlevel` value is set to 1, so all valid "labels" (subroutines) must return an errorlevel equal zero via `exit /B 0` command. Also, the error message can be hidden redirecting it to NUL.

See this example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:start
cls
echo One
echo Two
set /p PROGRAM=What you want to do? 
call :%PROGRAM% 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 echo Error: option not valid
pause
goto start

:One
echo Option One
exit /B 0

:Two
echo Option Two
exit /B 0
```

Anyway, you should use `choice` command for this instead of `set /P`...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have no label `:start` hence any routine attempting to `goto start` will cause a "label not found" error and terminate the program. If you've run this by point-click-and-giggle, then the window will appear simply to close.

Debugging batch scripts is far easier if you run `cmd` as such errors will then be displayed.

Comment: ps I added the :start at the very begining

Comment: After `set /p PROGRAM= What do you want do?` perhaps `goto %program%` might assist. Problem there is suppose you type `btfzk`. It's unlikely that such a command exists, so you'll get `goto not found`. You could fix this with `for %%a in (create shutdown photos) do if /i "%%a"=="%program%" goto %program%` - since `btfzk` isn't in the list, batch will proceed to the next line, where you'd put say `goto start`

Comment: @AnnoyingRain5 You wrote such a large batch file and don't know what a command prompt window is and how to open it? I can't believe that. However, Microsoft described it on page [Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813.aspx). Well, you don't need to open the command prompt as administrator for testing your batch file. So you have to just left click in Windows start menu in __Accessories__ of __All Programs__ on __Command prompt__ or enter __cmd__ in __Start Search box__ and hit key ENTER.